# How to make NumberPicker non-recurring

Tags: android, repeat, recurring, numberpicker

Is there any attribute to tell a (standard) NumberPicker to stop after its last value?
E.g. if my MinValue was 0 and my MaxValue was 5 the NumberPicker just repeats itself after the 5, so that the user could scroll endlessly.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

If You had set min/max value, try this:

```
yourNumberPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
```

does this work for you?

### EDIT

For TimePicker:

```
timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
   public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
     if(hourOfDay>max) {
       TimePicker.setHour(max):
     }
     updateDisplay(hourOfDay, minute);
   }
});
```

It's not a tested code, but this could be the way you could do this.

Comment: It works like a charm. Exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much Opiatefuchs!

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know the equivalent for a TimePicker by any chance?

Comment: For TimePicker this is not possible in this way. There are different ways to do this. For Example, you could do Your own TimePicker. Or, an easier way, set the TimePicker to an OnTimeChangedListener and every time your max value is reached, use the setCurrentMinute/setCurrentHour method and set your min/max values. I try to give you an example later, but now I must hurry up to go to work.

Comment: see my edit...its not tested, but it could work in a similar way

Comment: Thanks Opiatefuchs, your code somewhat does what I asked for :-) I just hoped that there would be a nice and clean way of doing this as with the NumberPicker. Now the user can actually see that there are other Numbers available but they're just unreachable. I might have to look into custom pickers a little more to get this done. Thanks anyway!

Comment: One thing to note about `NumberPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(boolean)` - system decides whether to wrap or not wrap depending on the range of the values so this method should be called *after* setting the min/max values.

Answer (score 8):

This [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24963508/2630035) helped me:

```
public void updatePickerValues(String[] newValues){
  picker.setDisplayedValues(null);
  picker.setMinValue(0);
  picker.setMaxValue(newValues.length -1);
  picker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
  picker.setDisplayedValues(newValues);
}
```

Apparently the order matters.