# Android NumberPicker wraps values when displayed values are changed

Tags: java, android, numberpicker

I have an android `Dialog` with a 3 `numberpickers` inside. Changing the 3rd picker triggers a change in the displayed values of the first 2 `pickers`. However I've noticed when I change the displayed values, and call

```
setWrapSelectorWheel(false)
```

it still shows the new values as wrapped visually (I can see the last value above the first one).

If I touch the picker it suddenly snaps into non wrap selector wheel. What's odd is I call

```
getWrapSelectoWheel()
```

after setting the displayed values and it returns false... just like I set it. But visually it's wrong.

Any ideas what's going on?

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm still dealing with the same problem, setting the picker programmatically resets the wrap visuals.

Answer (score 15):

I found a solution, Daniel was on the right track, however it appears that `initializeSelectorWheelIndices` is actually a bad thing once you've already set your values. Because of this, you need to call `setMinValue` and `setMaxValue` BEFORE you set your values. However, if you already have an array set on your picker, if you call `setMaxValue` with a higher value than the current array, it will give you a `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception.

The solution then is to clear the old display values, set your max value, *then* you can call `setWrapSelectorWheel` and `setDisplayValues`:

```
public void updatePickerValues(String[] newValues){
  picker.setDisplayedValues(null);
  picker.setMinValue(0);
  picker.setMaxValue(newValues.length -1);
  picker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
  picker.setDisplayedValues(newValues);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what version of Android you're running but I would suggest you read the [source code for the NumberPicker (v4.2.2)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/widget/NumberPicker.java). Perhaps you need to trigger a call to the private method `initializeSelectorWheelIndices` which can be done via a call to some of the public methods.

Although I do think your usage of the picker, by changing the wrapping flag part way through, does seem a little unusual. Don't you want this behaviour to be consistent? In which case make a call to `setWrapSelectorWheel` once after you've set your min and max values and then leave it alone.

Answer (score 1):

I've verified this behavior as well on kitkat. It's a bug. Couldn't find an existing report so I created a new one here: [bug# 98319](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=98319&thanks=98319&ts=1421441640)

Per previous answers I found that making setWrapSelectorWheel(false) the last call after all setup calls will work for most scenarios. In my case I'm dynamically changing limits of the NumberPicker as the user is interacting and I just can't get it to behave 100%. I'm opting to live with the wrap selector.